# Google scripts every minute trigger not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following script

```
    function scraper() {
        var url = 'http://gpa.shet.com.aspx';
        var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1im78ip4Wcmb1xbfZs8Lqy3-LP1SU9rC8E5OfKbOjJDg');
        //var sss = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
        var sheet = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
        var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
        var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
        var contentText = response.getContentText();
        var pr = sheet.getRange('A1:Z1000');
        var cstring = contentText.tostring;
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var NHL = "New Agent";
        var nlength = contentText.length;
        // ui.alert(nlength);
        //ui.alert(contentText);
        //var g = 5;
        var clength = 200000;
        ///
        var temp = contentText;
        var count = (temp.match(/New Hot Lead/g) || []).length;
        var C6 = sheet.getRange('C6');
        var C8 = sheet.getRange('C8');
        var C10 = sheet.getRange('C10').getValue();
        var C10r = sheet.getRange('C10');

        if (count > 0) {
            var d = new Date();
            var hrs = d.getHours();
            var mins = d.getMinutes();
            var time1 = hrs + ":" + mins;

            if (C6.isBlank() == true) {
                C6.setValue(time1);
            } else if (C6.isBlank() == false) {
                C8.setValue(time1);
            }
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            C6.clear();
            C8.clear();
        }

        var time2 = 0.00347222222222222;

        if (C10 >= time2) {
            var D10 = sheet.getRange("D10");
            var alert = "NHLs for more than 5 minutes!";
            D10.setValue(alert);
            D10.setFontColor('Red');
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is not the code itself, since when I run it manually it does work the way it's expected. My problem is with the time-driven trigger. I have tried to manually set it for every minute, and to add the triggerbuilder code at the end and outside of the function, but it still won't work. What are some suggestions?

Comment: Just so you know, there are a lot of websites that don't appreciate being hit this often by a scraper-bot, and when they figure out what you're doing, they will block your IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sleep function for 60 seconds.

```
sleep(60000);
```